# How to get the queries to which an TFS work-item belongs?

Tags: tfs-workitem

Normally my team work with a big list of work-item and there are also lots of queries in Team Explorer.

Given an id of a work-item, how can I know which queries it belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

Queries are like SQL statement, so that you need to execute each query and look if the workitem is in the result of the query.